# Matching at least one of each value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I've got 2 tables, I want to select entries from one table, where there are entries in the second table for a list of items.

for example:

entry

```
id=1 requirements=(1,2,3)

id=2 requirements=(1,3,5)
```

submission

```
id=1 entry=1 requirement=1

id=2 entry=2 requirement=2

id=3 entry=3 requirement=3
```

Would select entry `id=1`, but **not** entry `id=2` (so `WHERE IN` doesn't do the job)

*edit actual datasets:

INSERT INTO `submission` (`entry_id`, `requirement_id`, `submission_id`) VALUES
(17, 1, 1),
(43, 1, 2),
(57, 0, 3),
(57, 0, 4),
(1, 1, 5),
(26, 1, 6),
(40, 1, 7),
(40, 1, 8),
(40, 1, 9),
(40, 1, 10),
(85, 1, 11),
(94, 1, 12),
(114, 0, 13),
(32, 1, 14),
(34, 0, 15);

INSERT INTO `entry` (`entry_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(5, 2),
(6, 1),
(7, 1),
(8, 1),
(9, 1),
(10, 1),
(11, 1),
(12, 1),
(13, 1),
(14, 1),
(15, 1);

INSERT INTO `category` (`category_id`, `requirement`) VALUES
(1, '1,2,3'),
(2, '1,2,4,5,6'),
(3, '1,2,4,5,6');

Comment: Could you provide REAL data instead of whatever this is? Is (1,2,3) a single text column? Does it contain the parentheses? Is there some relationship between id/id or id/entry in the tables? Huh?

Answer (score 0):

Find all rows in table 1 where there are 3 matching rows in table 2:

```
SELECT
  table1.id
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
  table2
ON
  table1.somecol = table2.somecol
GROUP BY
  table1.id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 3
```

I'd write the actual query for your data but I can't decipher your question.